# What is the 'War on Terror'?

Tags: political-philosophy, philosophy-of-war

It isn't War, as classically defined by [Clauswitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_von_Clausewitz#Theory_of_war), which is defined to be declared by states against states; states are of course the pre-eminant form of political organisation since the Peace of Westphalia which brought about the nation-state system.

One could say that defensive war is engaged in by a state when its territorial integrity is threatened in an existential manner by some aggressive state; whereas police action is carried out internally to remove internal threats to its organisation of small-scale insurgency.

Can we then say, that the war on terror is a kind of a police action carried out internationally?

Comment: It's a war on the American people. Haven't you noticed? The soldiers come home from Iraq and Afghanistan, join the local police force, dress up in military gear, and throw flashbang grenades in the faces of sleeping babies. http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-watch/wp/2014/05/30/georgia-toddler-critically-injured-by-polices-flash-grenade/ And the regime no longer uses the phrase "Global War on Terror." It's now called Overseas Contingency Operation. Orwell would be proud. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_on_Terror

Comment: @user4894 did you have a particular point about the Clausewitz? It doesn't seem constructive to rant in comments; we [have a chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) for that! :)

Comment: And of course if you have an answer to the question, it could go into an answer...

Comment: @JosephWeissman I took the question as a political comment rather than as a philosophical one; so I gave a political response. But surely if the question is to be taken at face value: "What is the 'war on terror?'" then my response is perfectly valid. Clearly I have not ranted. I have responded directly to the OP's question; which itself was not a matter of philosophy. Perhaps your concern is better directed at the OP? The text of the question used Clausewitz as a point of reference. The question itself is about the WOT, not about Clausewitz.

Comment: @user4894: its a political-philosophical question - to put it into context - its about the taxonomy of violence between states & non-state actors.

Comment: @MoziburUllah "the taxonomy of violence between states & non-state actors." -- Are you familiar with William Lind's work on fourth generation warfare? These days *many* conflicts are best understood as state versus non-state actors. This is in fact the nature of modern war. Governments that attempt to impose World War II type tactics and strategy on fourth generation wars are doomed to fail. http://www.antiwar.com/lind/?articleid=1702 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth-generation_warfare

Comment: @user4894: No, I'm not; but perhaps you want to put this into an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: @MoziburUllah I'd love to but I'd have to break down 40 years of US foreign policy, explain Lind's theory of fourth generation warfare, explain Colonel John Boyd's theory of the moral dimension of war; then bring in the militarization of the domestic police and the war on drugs culminating in a country that throws a flashbang grenade in the face of a sleeping baby to arrest some low-end meth dealer who wasn't even there. To me this is the war on terror. And I believe a close reading of recent history will bear me out. I just don't think I can get this all into a few paragraphs. Maybe later.

Comment: @MoziburUllah And where does the philosophical become the political? The name "Global War on Terror" was originally a designed piece of propaganda to get the American people to sign off on DHS, the PATRIOT act, and endless low-level conflicts in places where we don't even understand which side we're on. Of course this question is political. The very phrase "war on terror" is political. To even use the phrase is to take a political stance. Use it without irony and you subscribe to a worldview I oppose. So yes, this is totally political. I don't understand how anyone could deny that.

Comment: Oh it's war on Terrorism! Because of his accent, I thought Bush was announcing a war on Tourism. bahah.

Answer (score 3):

First, let's look at the phrase itself. The phrase, "The War on Terror" is a rhetorical construction that follows a long tradition in America:

- [The War on Poverty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_on_Poverty)
- [The War on Drugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_on_Drugs)
- [The War on Cancer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_on_Cancer)

During World War II, all of American society was mobilized toward one particular goal. Bureaucrats saw this and asked themselves if we could use the same efforts aimed at destruction pointed at other, more noble, targets. (Need to dig up a citation.) So, it has been common in America to speak of any societal mobilization as a "War on something" in the post World War II years, even without a formal declaration of War.

On the other hand, the War on Terror actually is, in some sense, a violent struggle, even if not a formally declared war. However, the formal declaration of war relies on a nation state. Some of the premise for the War on Terror is that there are parts of the world where, although there is an official border, no nation-state effectively controls the area, such as along the Afghanistan-Pakistan border.

I would disagree that it is simply an international police-action. That is one component of it (soldiers coming and acting as a police force), but a police force is not something that takes control of an area in the first place.

Comment: good points - particularly about the tradition of this rhetorical construct. I have come across the other three terms. The one reason that you pointed out for *not* calling an international police action - is that police action do not normally take control of territory. Now, police action is generally used for domestic situations - where the territory itself isn't under dispute. For action outside of the nation-state, this becomes  a problematic issue. Its a general rule of thumb that military action must take control of territory - what becomes of that territory

Comment: is a political issue. Traditionally there are wars of conquest and colonialism; the cold-war saw proxy wars, in which proxy territory was secured. The question is what is the status of territory secured in this 'War' or 'overseas contingency action'.

Comment: I'd also dispute the applicability of state theory in situations where there hasn't been an organic development of said process. Though there might not be an effective nation-state along the Afghan-Pak territory; I'd suggest that there will be other forms of political organisation.

Answer (score 0):

If Clauswitz defines war as necessarily state-against-state then the War on Terror isn't really a war : it's just a defensive move, because the taliban (etc) aren't a recognised state.

If police action is defined as carried out internally to remove internal threats, it's not really police action either because the influence comes from outside of the US state (I'm guessing that's a grey area, but on the whole probably true).

So either it is a war, and Clauswitz definition is flawed because war doens't have to be between two states, OR it's not a war - just a military operation.
But not a police operation (according to your definition) because of the origin of the threat.

According to you link, Clauswitz strived "to include more material on "people's war" and forms of war other than between states, but little of this material was included in the book" - so perhaps there's a definition missing there?

In the UK we've had to deal with the IRA bombing us for decades or more, with varying ferocity on both sides. It's never been described as a war though, and it's not a police matter; the military handle it. I don't think this necessarily sways any philosophical argument but it's another example of a similar thing.

Answer (score -1):

1. It's no war, because wars end. (Quote from The Wire)

   - I rest my case
2. If you want to know what it actually is. It's the response of a system to a perceived thread.